How to enable a spring-boot app for extension by users of the app
If i distribute my spring-boot application as a docker container, how can i enable users of my application to plugin custom behavior?
the application offers extension points where at start up it scans the classpath (or a given configurable path that can be mounted onto the container) for classes implementing given interfaces thus making these custom implementations available to the application?
my concern is:
the difference in versions of libraries used by the custom implementations and the versions of libraries used by my application

i didn't understand anything... u want to distribute a spring boot app IN a docker container and at the same time offer Service Loader Feature (or spring equivalent) which only works with Jars on a classpath? Are you mixing the concepts or am I missing something?

thank you for the feedback @j-asgarov , i re-worded the question
